# Unexpected token; 'constructor, function, accessor or variable' expected

Tags: typescript

Sorry for the newbie question, but I am trying to learn type script.

I have the following class

```html
class indexGridFunctions
{

    //Error on the var
    var blocksPerRow: (windowWidth:number)=>number
    = function (windowWidth)
    {
        return Math.floor(windowWidth / 12);
    };

    var blocksPerColumn: (windowHeight: number) => number
    = function (windowHeight)
    {
        return Math.floor(windowHeight / 17);
    };

    shirtsToDisplay: () => number
    = function ()
    {
        return blocksPerRow * blocksPerColumn;
    };

}
```

I am getting an error at the first var. the error is "Unexpected token; 'constructor, function, accessor or variable' expected".

What am I doing wrong?

TIA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `var`. Its invalid syntax within the class body. Fixed code :

```
class indexGridFunctions {

    blocksPerRow: (windowWidth: number) => number
    = function (windowWidth) {
        return Math.floor(windowWidth / 12);
    };

    blocksPerColumn: (windowHeight: number) => number
    = function (windowHeight) {
        return Math.floor(windowHeight / 17);
    };

    shirtsToDisplay: () => number
    =  () => {
        return this.blocksPerRow(123) * this.blocksPerColumn(123);
    };

}
```

I also did other fixes for your code in the code ive presented:

- `blocksPerRow` and `blocksPerColumn` is not defined. Use `this.`. And its a function so call it `(123)`.
- Prefer `arrow ()=>` over `function` if you are going to use `=` (more https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA)

Comment: Thank you so much. I have rewritten this dozens of times trying different variations. the this. was what I was missing from my original code base. Thank you so much for helping a newbie out. I will also add your other recommendations into my code.

Comment: Note that all of these were pointed out by the TypeScript compiler *at compile time* ;)